# Upgrading from bitcoin-0.14.3 to bitcoin-0.25. I have a problem with a fork and different hashed keys that don't match genesis block

Tags: c++

I have a slightly modified fork of bitcoin-0.14. It's mostly a name change and hash key change of the bitcoin code. I have updated the fork to bitcoin-25, but I cannot get passed this error. It has essentially all the same line of code except for a different hash key to create the genesis block. The key that fails the check is:

"**0x00001ef7e03e773817a36c267d6f431412a3678dec49b4171f86ce419abcddea**".

I added a printf, and it prints a different key before the assert() that doesn't match the above key. I don't know what is causing a different key to be generated. I'm guessing its something to do with pszTimestamp, the ParseHex() key, and assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock()).I updated the appropriate code from the old fork into the new bitcoin code, which is just a few lines of hash keys, and making sure the GENESIS TIME, DIFFICULTY, and block were the same. But I get:

**MainParams::CMainParams(): Assertion `consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x00001ef7e03e773817a36c267d6f431412a3678dec49b4171f86ce419abcddea")' failed.
**
I believe the problem is with this hashed genesis block key:

"**0x00001ef7e03e773817a36c267d6f431412a3678dec49b4171f86ce419abcddea**"

and

**pszTimestamp** = "**New York Times 8/Sep/2017 Equifax Says Cyberattack May Have Affected 143 Million Customers**";const CScript scriptPubKey = CScript() << ParseHex("**03facfdfc22816528518884608350d828e1403dd142d2276303b5b6da7a**") << OP_CHECKSIG;

Regardless of what I do, even though I believe all the changes are correct, the key that is hashed out doesn't match I assume the genesis block (block 0), which should be "0x00001ef7e03e773817a36c267d6f431412a3678dec49b4171f86ce419abcddea" when using the pszTimeStamp and ParseHex() keys.

From the old src/chainparams.cpp:

```
#define GENESIS_TIME 1510225282
#define GENESIS_DIFFICULTY 0x1e7fffff

void MineGenesisBlock(CBlock &genesis);

static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(const char* pszTimestamp, const CScript& scriptPubKey, uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward) {
    CMutableTransaction txNew;
    txNew.nVersion = 2;
    txNew.vin.resize(1);
    txNew.vout.resize(1);
    unsigned int height = 0;

    txNew.vin[0].scriptSig = CScript() << height << std::vector<unsigned char>((const unsigned char*)pszTimestamp, (const unsigned char*)pszTimestamp + strlen(pszTimestamp));
    txNew.vout[0].nValue = genesisReward;
    txNew.vout[0].scriptPubKey = scriptPubKey;

    CBlock genesis;
    genesis.nTime    = nTime;
    genesis.nBits    = nBits;
    genesis.nNonce   = nNonce;
    genesis.nVersion = nVersion;
    genesis.vtx.push_back(MakeTransactionRef(std::move(txNew)));
    genesis.hashPrevBlock.SetNull();
    genesis.hashMerkleRoot = BlockMerkleRoot(genesis);
    
    return genesis;
}

static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward) {
    const char* pszTimestamp = "New York Times 8/Sep/2017 Equifax Says Cyberattack May Have Affected 143 Million Customers";
    const CScript scriptPubKey = CScript() << ParseHex("03facfdfc22816528518884608350d828e1403dd142d2276303b5b6da7a8b854a1") << OP_CHECKSIG;
    
    return CreateGenesisBlock(pszTimestamp, scriptPubKey, nTime, nNonce, nBits, nVersion, genesisReward);
}

genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(GENESIS_TIME, 2314582475, GENESIS_DIFFICULTY, 1, 50 * COIN);
//MineGenesisBlock(genesis);

consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();

assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x00001ef7e03e773817a36c267d6f431412a3678dec49b4171f86ce419abcddea"));
assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0x5a5fbc104e0a21be0a745d014a87340408ef288cc4ca6ab21fa0d7565e4f6a76"));

// Note that of those with the service bits flag, most only support a subset of possible options
vSeeds.push_back(CDNSSeedData("..."));

base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,55);
base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,5);
base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,128);
base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = boost::assign::list_of(0x04)(0x88)(0xB2)(0x1E).convert_to_container<std::vector<unsigned char> >();
base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = boost::assign::list_of(0x04)(0x88)(0xAD)(0xE4).convert_to_container<std::vector<unsigned char> >();

vFixedSeeds = std::vector<SeedSpec6>(pnSeed6_main, pnSeed6_main + ARRAYLEN(pnSeed6_main));

fMiningRequiresPeers = true;
fDefaultConsistencyChecks = false;
fRequireStandard = true;
fMineBlocksOnDemand = false;

checkpointData = (CCheckpointData) {
    boost::assign::map_list_of
    ( 0, uint256S("0x"))
};

chainTxData = ChainTxData{};
}
```

That works fine in bitcoin verison 0.14. In 0.25, I get:

bitcoind bitcoind: kernel/chainparams.cpp:128: CMainParams::CMainParams(): Assertion `consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("**0x00001ef7e03e773817a36c267d6f431412a3678dec49b4171f86ce419abcddea**")' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

Here is the code in 0.25 modified from the forked 0.14 code that I can't figure out. Tried setting txNew.nVersion to "2" and using the old CBlock CreateGenesisBlock() from 0.14 in 0.25 but no luck, same error.

```
#define GENESIS_TIME 1510225282
#define GENESIS_DIFFICULTY 0x1e7fffff

static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(const char* pszTimestamp, const CScript& genesisOutputScript, uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward) {
    CMutableTransaction txNew;
    txNew.nVersion = 1;
    txNew.vin.resize(1);
    txNew.vout.resize(1);
    txNew.vin[0].scriptSig = CScript() << 486604799 << CScriptNum(4) << std::vector<unsigned char>((const unsigned char*)pszTimestamp, (const unsigned char*)pszTimestamp + strlen(pszTimestamp));
    txNew.vout[0].nValue = genesisReward;
    txNew.vout[0].scriptPubKey = genesisOutputScript;

    CBlock genesis;
    genesis.nTime    = nTime;
    genesis.nBits    = nBits;
    genesis.nNonce   = nNonce;
    genesis.nVersion = nVersion;
    genesis.vtx.push_back(MakeTransactionRef(std::move(txNew)));
    genesis.hashPrevBlock.SetNull();
    genesis.hashMerkleRoot = BlockMerkleRoot(genesis);
    
    return genesis;
}

static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward) {
    const char* pszTimestamp = "New York Times 8/Sep/2017 Equifax Says Cyberattack May Have Affected 143 Million Customers";
    const CScript genesisOutputScript = CScript() << ParseHex("03facfdfc22816528518884608350d828e1403dd142d2276303b5b6da7a8b854a1") << OP_CHECKSIG;
    
    return CreateGenesisBlock(pszTimestamp, genesisOutputScript, nTime, nNonce, nBits, nVersion, genesisReward);
}

genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(GENESIS_TIME, 2314582475, GENESIS_DIFFICULTY, 1, 50 * COIN);
consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();

assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x00001ef7e03e773817a36c267d6f431412a3678dec49b4171f86ce419abcddea"));
assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0x5a5fbc104e0a21be0a745d014a87340408ef288cc4ca6ab21fa0d7565e4f6a76"));
```

I tried changing txNew around, but same error. Tried other things, but kept getting the *dea assertion error when running executable.

Update the keys, hash, hex and have it return genesisblock 0 key hash "**0x00001ef7e03e773817a36c267d6f431412a3678dec49b4171f86ce419abcddea**"

Instead, for genesis block 0, I get an entirely different key and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you mine the block by yourself? how did you get to the values?

Comment: I figured it out. The hash code was in some other files that I overlooked. Had to diff until I found it.